# Python+ Selenium Error al abrir multiples ventanas

Tags: python, selenium, scraping

estoy haciendo un pequeño scrapping a la página de mismarcadores, pero tengo conocimiento básico en Selenium. En la iteración de elementos, cada elemento abre una nueva ventana, extrae los datos y luego lo cierra. El problema es que el primer elemento iterado funciona normal, pero en el segundo elemento me sale el error de sesión invalida.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

# Ruta al controlador de ChromeDriver (asegúrate de haberlo descargado y configurado correctamente)
chrome_driver_path = r"C:\Users\Armando\Desktop\scripts\selenium\driver\chromedriver"

# Inicializar el servicio del controlador de ChromeDriver
service = Service(chrome_driver_path)

# Inicializar el navegador Chrome
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)

url = "https://www.flashscore.pe/?rd=mismarcadores.com"
driver.get(url)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
elementos_partidos = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.event__match.event__match--twoLine")

for n,elemento in enumerate(elementos_partidos):

    actions = ActionChains(driver)
    actions.move_to_element(elemento).click().perform()
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    #cambiamos el control a la ventana emergente
 
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
 
    driver.close()
 
    
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
# Cerrar el navegador
driver.quit()
```

El error que me sale es:

```
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSessionIdException: Message: invalid session id
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x002C8893+48451]
    (No symbol) [0x0025B8A1]
    (No symbol) [0x00164F20]
    (No symbol) [0x00187A42]
    (No symbol) [0x00188F2D]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00528E3A+2540266]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00568959+2801161]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0056295C+2776588]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00352280+612144]
    (No symbol) [0x00264F6C]
```

Gracias!